# Cannot display images which are locally stored with SLD style

Tags: sld

I'm trying to load some pictures into my map. They are supposed to be images which are in a local folder of my pc. This is my SLD file:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name/>
        <UserStyle>
            <Name>Leghe: grafico a torta</Name>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <Rule>
                  <Title>Large</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                            <ogc:PropertyIsLike wildCard="*" singleChar="." escape="!">
                                <ogc:PropertyName>classificazione</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:Literal>servito tramite ns cliente</ogc:Literal>
                            </ogc:PropertyIsLike>
                    </ogc:Filter> 
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>4000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <ExternalGraphic>
                                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="cliente.png"/>
                                <Format>image.png</Format>
                            </ExternalGraphic>
                            <Size>
                                <ogc:Literal>70</ogc:Literal>
                            </Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

I have put both the sld file and the cliente.png in the Style Directory as said here http://girona-geoserver-workshop.readthedocs.org/en/latest/styling/styles.html but that's the result

[image]

what I'm doing wrong?? Please help me!!

Comment: Another thing... I followed this suggestion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346001/geoserver-sld-styling-issue-with-external-graphics-and-attribute-rules but it still doesn't work, despite the fact that xlink:href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/styles/cliente.png actually returns the images if I write it in the browser

Comment: try <Format>image/png</Format>

Comment: done it already...wasn't working...

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved the problem. I hope it might be useful to someone else...

This is the string I needed it so that GeoServer could see my image

```
xlink:href="file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Boundless/OpenGeo/jetty/webapps/geoserver/data/styles/cliente.png"/>
```

It finally worked! And I also find out that GeoServer cannot access all the folder of your pc, so watch out especially when working on a pc which has a domain. The reason GeoServer couldn't "access" the image was that it didn't have the permission to access the folder (despite I'm an administrator user).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have permission to write to /.../tomcat/temp